# How to open simultaneous SSH sessions to 100 elements when server permits only 10 elements per session?

Tags: linux, ssh, shell, script

I am running a script to simultaneously run SSH sessions to 100 elements but my server can only permit 10 elements to be accessed at a time. My script is like below:

```
cat  ip | while read ip
do
      connect.sh $ip >> ip.OK &
done
```

`connect.sh` is the main script to SSH to all IPs and run a specific command.

How can I modify my script to run the 100 elements by dividing it to 10 per session, making 10 sessions inside the script?

Comment: Apart from the 2 answers, you could always allow all 100 by changing `MaxSessions` in the `sshd_config` file and restarting the daemon..

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately, this is a limitation set by the admin.

Comment: So, not your server then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command `xargs` :

```
cat ip|xargs -P 10 -n 1 connect.sh >> ip.OK
```

`-P` gives the number of parallel tasks, `-n` indicates that `connect.sh` should be given 1 argument at a time.

`parallel` is a similar command.

It is not strictly equivalent with the principle of divising 100 per 10, but it will manage to use more effectively the 10 connection which are permitted and each time an connect.sh is done a new one is started.

If you want individual output files :

```
cat ip|xargs -P 10 -n 1 -I {} sh -c 'connect.sh {} >> {}.OK'
```

Here `{}` will be replaced by each argument.

Comment: thank you for your input.  greatly appreciated with the explanation that made me further understand.

Comment: Hello Frederic,  I just tried your input and it went very well as expected.  I am just trying to save the output of each IP as one file like $ip.ok.  So if i have something like 10  IPs, i should also have 10 output files.

Comment: Answer edited to include this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This example code will loop and wait for 60 seconds every 10 lines:

```
maxcnt=10
fcnt=0

while read -r fname
do
    echo "execute command for $fname"
    ((++fcnt % maxcnt == 0)) && sleep 60
done < file.txt
```

Modeled after the post
[bash script to handle 9000 lines of text by groups of 25](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75348254/bash-script-to-handle-9000-lines-of-text-by-groups-of-25).

Comment: thanks @harrymc.  will surely help and consider.  it will be a helpful input.